# Laravel DotEnv not reading server environment variables

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get a Laravel app working in an automated deployment setup.

Everything deploys fine, but I get the following 500 hundred error.

```
Illuminate\Encryption\MissingAppKeyException: No application encryption key has been specified.
```

Now, there is no .env file but the variables are all defined already on the server. If I ssh into my server and type env I can see **APP_KEY** in the list with the right value, but my Laravel app can not see it.

I have tried refreshing caches etc, but still, it doesn't work.

Can Laravel not use server environment variables?

Comment: how did you set these environmental vars on the server?

Comment: check again if your `.env` is named exactly like that, and in the root directory of your project (that is next to the `app` and `composer.json` files). You dont want it in the public directory for instance.

Comment: There is no .env file

Comment: What are you using to do this deployment ? are you using Docker?

Comment: Yes, it's docker/kubernetes

Comment: Have you set APP_ENV=production ?

Answer (score -2):

if APP_KEY already in .env, may you run php artisan config:cache.

Comment: I have already tried that, as stated in my question